# implement mixin for angular service using this.http

Tags: angular, typescript

This is with Angular 5 and typescript 2.9.2

I have a class that is a service that will both implement api and act as state for a user story in the app. At the start it looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../core/services/authentication.service';
import { HttpErrorService } from '../../core/services/http-error.service';

import { manufacturersUrl } from '../constants';
import { Manufacturers } from '../interfaces/manufacturers.interface';
import { Device } from '../interfaces/device.interface';

@Injectable()
export class LocalService {
 public newDevice: Device;

  constructor (
    private http: HttpClient,
    private httpErrorService: HttpErrorService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { 
      super();
      this.newDevice = {MAC : ''};
  }

  /**
   * getManufacturers api call for first page
   * @returns Observable
   */
  getManufacturers (): Observable<Manufacturers> {
    const requestBody = { 'num': 12 };

    return this.http.post<Manufacturers>(manufacturersUrl, requestBody).pipe(
      catchError(this.httpErrorService.handleError<Manufacturers>(`getManufacturers`))
    );
  }
}
```

I would be happier if my transaction code didnt *clutter the view* in this service .. so I'd like to move `getManufacturers` to a file like *./extensionApi.js* and import it for use, something like:

```
import { getManufacturers } from './extensionApi.ts';
//...
  private getManufacturers: Function;

  constructor (
    private http: HttpClient,
    private httpErrorService: HttpErrorService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { 
      this.newDevice = {MAC : ''};

    this.getManufacturers = getManufacturers.bind(this);
  }
```

This approach can work, but not here. I am getting a compile error: `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments` related to the `this.http` parts of that function.

How can I keep the modularity of my design, but get around the compile issue?

### addendum

these three lines complete the answer below

```
  constructor(http:HttpClient, httpErrorService: HttpErrorService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { 
      super(http, httpErrorService);
```

#### implementation

LocalService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthenticationService } from '@core/services/authentication.service';
import { HttpErrorService } from '@core/services/http-error.service';
import { Device } from '@usage/interfaces/device.interface';

import ApiClient from './extension-api';

@Injectable()
export class LocalService extends ApiClient {
 public newDevice: Device;

  constructor(http: HttpClient, httpErrorService: HttpErrorService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { 
      super(http, httpErrorService);

      this.newDevice = {MAC : ''};
  }
}
```

#### extension-api

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpErrorService } from '@core/services/http-error.service';
import { manufacturersUrl } from '@usage/constants';
import { Manufacturers } from '@usage/interfaces/manufacturers.interface';

/**
* getManufacturers api call for first page
* @returns Observable
*/
export default class ApiService {
  constructor (private http: HttpClient,
    private httpErrorService: HttpErrorService){}

  getManufacturers(): Observable<Manufacturers> {
    const requestBody = { 'num': 12 };

    return this.http.post<Manufacturers>(manufacturersUrl, requestBody).pipe(
      catchError(this.httpErrorService.handleError<Manufacturers>(`getManufacturers`))
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: I can see why this was voted down after only 30 seconds -- obviously no thought went into my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're injecting `HttpClient` in `LocalService`, then the HTTP calls should really be made within that class. Using imported functions is fine, but in this case it's really mixing up paradigms as you are also binding the `this` context in the funciton - it's like `class composition` and `functional programming` with `OOD` usage of the `this` context

A more standard `OOD` approach would be to extend a base class that has a `getManufacturers` function. The base class would inject HttpClient, and make the `post` call. If you are not going to reuse the base class, it might not be worth it though

The first version of your service looks absolutely standard btw, so I myself wouldn't change it

```
export class BaseService {
  constructor(/*inject same classes as LocalService*/) {
  }
  public getManufacturers (): Observable<Manufacturers> {
     .....
  }
}

export class LocalService extends BaseService {

 constructor(/*inject the dependencies*/) {
      super(/* pass the dependencies to the BaseService*/)
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show explicitly the extension method that would work?

Comment: I had actually tried this but I can't get rid of the red squiggly under LocalService -- I don't see how to satisfy it's call to super `(/* pass the dependencies to the BaseService*/)` -- it complains `'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class.ts(17009)`

Comment: neither `super(...arguments)` nor `super(this.http, this.httpErrorService);` seem to work

Comment: it seems like I _can_ do it as long asI don't redeclare them in the outer class !